# How to split a name from middle name and last name in a list with Bash Shell Script

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, terminal

First of all, thank you so much for taking some time out to help me out!
I've been trying to figure out a way to split a full name into First, Middle, and Last names using awk and sed in bash shell without any success, this is an example of the names.

```
Kent D. Hones
Akelli Same Lizarraga
Sherein Rahmi
Theresa Q. Callins
Vanessa M. Dewson
Behzad Gazloo
Jim M. Skolen
Sherry Marie Wanaa
```

These are the bash commands that I've been trying to use.

```
awk -F"." '{print $1}' listnames.csv > output.csv
sed -e 's/*.//g' <  listnames.csv > output.csv
```

The output of the used commands are:

for `awk -F"." '{print $1}' listnames.csv > output.csv` returns an empty output.csv
for `sed -e 's/*.//g' <  listnames.csv > output.csv` returns the exact same list:

```
Kelly D. Hynes
Aketzalli Gamez Lizarraga
Shervin Rahimi
Theresa M. Collins
Vanessa L. Dawson
Behzad Garagozloo
James M. Skaalen
Shannon Marie Wenaa
```

The desired output is to have at least two list of

```
First name 
Aketzalli  
Shervin
Theresa
Vanessa
Behzad
James
Shannon

Last name
Hynes
Lizarraga
Rahimi
Collins
Dawson
Garagozloo
Skaalen
Wenaa
```

I was thinking that maybe I could use the "." in the Middle name to differentiate them but that would not work for distinguishing between last names and middle names.

Any help, insights, or feedback would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code attempts as well as the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the sample inputs); what happens if the name conisst of more than 3 space-delmiited strings?

Comment: how do you plan on using the final result? just print to stdout? load into (`bash`) variables for further processing? something else?

Comment: I'm planning on exporting to a spreadsheet and/or a database.

Comment: How would you handle for example _Edward Lodewijk van Halen_?

Comment: Hang on - do you ONLY want the first and last names output to 2 separate files?

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and other [Awesome Falsehoods](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{print $1, (NF>2 ? $2 : ""), $NF}' file
Kent,D.,Hones
Akelli,Same,Lizarraga
Sherein,,Rahmi
Theresa,Q.,Callins
Vanessa,M.,Dewson
Behzad,,Gazloo
Jim,M.,Skolen
Sherry,Marie,Wanaa
```

To print the first and last names to 2 separate files as you now show your desired output to be would just be:

```
awk '{print $1 > "first"; print $NF > "last"}' file
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank line at the top of the output when I run this. Any ideas? And, thanks for showing us how to use awk better (and, yeah, not need sed).

Comment: You're welcome. If there's a blank line at the top of the output then it's because there's a blank line at the top of the input.

Comment: Shucks, nevermind, my window just wide enough to fit the whole command, and then the cursor wrapped... just widening my terminal window "fixed" it. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk to separate the names into comma separated values and then use sed to trim any whitespace characters.

```
awk '{if (NF == 3) {print $1",",$2",",$3} else {print $1",,"$2}}' listnames.csv |sed 's/[ .]//g'
```

- `if (NF == 3) ...` This tests if the name contains a middle name or not in order to separate the values properly.
- `sed 's/[ .]//g'` We use sed to remove whitespace and periods.